# Is there any cross-platform SDK available for ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cross-platform

I am using Corona SDK for app development in Android and iPhone. I am working on windows 8 OS. I want to make apps for ubuntu. Is there any cross-platform SDK available for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

[V-Play](http://v-play.net) (I'm part of their developer team) is a cross platform engine that also supports Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10, 13.04 & 13.10. It's specialized for 2D games, but depending on the requirements of your app, it may still be a viable choice.